# Selecting xsd:element from complexType with SCD

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, scd

I'm trying to select the child element of complexType with SCD, but the SCD selects a complexType. The SCD documentation is poor and I don't understand, how to select the child element properly. 
Here ist XSD snippet:

```
<xsd:complexType name="request">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element form="unqualified"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="partner"
                        type="ns1:Partner" />
          <xsd:element form="unqualified"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="foo"
                        type="xsd:anyType" />
          <xsd:element form="unqualified"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="foo2"
                        type="xsd:anyType" />    
      </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I've written the following binding:

```
<bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http:/mynamespace.com/xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
       <package name="com.otherpackage.xsd" />
    </schemaBindings>
    <bindings scd="/~tns:request:schemaElement:foo">
           <class ref="com.othernamespace.OhterFoo" />
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="/~tns:request:schemaElement:foo2">
           <class ref="com.othernamespace.OhterFoo" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

I've also tried following binding, but with this one it doesn't even generate the source code.

```
<bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http:/mynamespace.com/xsd">
        <schemaBindings>
           <package name="com.otherpackage.xsd" />
        </schemaBindings>
        <bindings scd="/type::tns:request/model:sequence/schemaElement::tns:foo">
               <class ref="com.othernamespace.OhterFoo" />
        </bindings>
        <bindings scd="/type::tns:request/model:sequence/schemaElement::tns:foo2">
               <class ref="com.othernamespace.OhterFoo" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: when you write `<class ref="com.othernamespace.OhterFoo" />` it refers to existing class and does not generate one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `model::sequence` double `::` as provided in this [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-ref/#section-path-examples)